# How to search for sent files in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Is there a way to search for sent files in Facebook Messenger? I have tried to search for file names in the search in conversation feature, but it doesn't work.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the information panel in www.messenger.com already have this. Not sure if this is new or not.

[image]